# How to use multiple arguments when querying Laravel Eloquent results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am querying DB posts via a Laravel eloquent controller and would like to first filter the posts and then paginate.

```
$filter = ['author_id' => $id, 'status' => 'live', 'type' => $type];
$posts = Post::where($filter)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
$posts = Post::paginate(1, ['*'], 'page', $page);

return $posts;
```

Of course currently it is only going to paginate. How can I combine both `$posts` so that the filtered results are paginated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as just chain those methods like:

```
$posts = Post::where($filter)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->paginate(1, ['*'], 'page', $page);
```

Comment: Excellent! Makes sense now - thought the `::` was required for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify the solution like this and this will become more flexible.

```
$filter = ['author_id' => $id, 'status' => 'live', 'type' => $type];

$posts = new Post();
$posts = $posts->where($filter);
$posts = $posts->orderBy('id','desc');
$posts = $posts->paginate(1, ['*'], 'page', $page);

return $posts;
```